# Indent text following a <br>

Tags: javascript, html, css, text-indent

I have a web page that presents flowing text, with line breaks (`br`) interspersed inside `span` tags. I would like every `span` that follows a `br` to have an indent. Is it possible to do this with pure CSS? I would prefer to do this without manipulating the text itself. (it's possible, but messy) Note that the `br` tags are *inside* the `span` tags.

Here is some example code and my attempt at doing it in pure CSS.

```css
.text + br {
  text-indent: 1.5em;
}
.text > br + .text {
  text-indent: 1.5em;
}
```

```html
<span class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</span>
<span class="text">Donec accumsan tortor at maximus vehicula.<br></span>
<span class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</span>
<span class="text">Donec accumsan tortor at maximus vehicula.<br></span>
```

**Update**: this may be impossible to do in pure CSS. My project utilizes jQuery so a solution using jQuery is acceptable.

**Update 2**: `text-indent` in CSS is only supported for block elements. Using `display: block` on the span tags will make indentation work, but then the content needs to be merged between span tags to prevent any unwanted block element newlines. An alternative is to insert a number of `&nbsp;` instead of setting a CSS class.

Comment: For your attempts to work HTML must be `<span class="text">Text</span><br>`.

Comment: Since it's messy to change the text, is there any other way to make it work?

Comment: text-indent only applies to block-level elements such as <p>,<table>,and <blockquote> http://webdesign.about.com/od/styleproperties/p/blsptextindent.htm

Comment: The code is indeed messy—and impossible to style the desired way with CSS. Are you sure you want to keep working with it instead of fixing the markup?

Comment: Jukka: Oh I would very much like to fix the markup, but that'd be a lot of work. It's a good advise for most cases, but in this case I want to avoid manipulating the text as far as possible.

Answer (score 3):

I don't believe there are any css selectors that will allow you to **target the parent element** *if it contains a given child*. You may be forced to use JavaScript (unless you're willing to massage the data in such a way that will allow you to use css selectors for the desired formatting).

A jQuery solution is shown below:

```js
$( ".text:has(br)" ).next(".text").addClass( "indent" );
```

```css
span {
    display:block;
}
.indent {
    text-indent: 1.5em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</span>
<span class="text">Donec accumsan tortor at maximus vehicula.<br></span>
<span class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</span>
<span class="text">Donec accumsan tortor at maximus vehicula. asdfasdfasdf a<br></span>
```

Comment: You don't need jQuery at all.

Comment: True, you could use a native JavaScript implementation to achieve the same result.

Comment: Actually, I'm using jQuery, so it's fine. The code above is close - but it should add the indent to every `span` _following_ a br. Like this: `$('.text:has(br)').next('.text').addClass('indent');`

Comment: David: If the answer has a bug, edit the answer. Not everyone in the future will see your comment.

Comment: Not so much a bug... more of a misunderstanding.

Comment: Ok, I edited the post. When it's been peer reviewed I will answer-mark it.

Answer (score -1):

since text-indent only applies to block-level elements, maybe this may work for you

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("p").css("text-indent","1.5em");
 

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
<p class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
Donec accumsan tortor at maximus vehicula.<br/>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
Donec accumsan tortor at maximus vehicula.<br/></p>



</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Pointlessly uses JavaScript and even jQuery for styling, and guaranteed to fail: it is useless to style `p` elements when there are none.